# California code requirements for electrical panel placement height

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, electrical-panel

I'm trying to get some wires to reach the bottom of my electrical panel. How high off the floor can I put my panel and still meet code requirements... or what section of which code can I find this? I'm having trouble parsing the legal nightmare.

Comment: Trying to get some wires to reach? Uh-oh. Measure twice, cut once.

Comment: There was an existing box and someone before me was snapping tabs off of twins to overload the panel. I'm trying to make the twins from the top reach the notched contacts at the bottom, where they belong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no minimum height in the National Electrical Code, that I'm aware of. The maximum height, is based on the maximum height of the breakers that are contained within the panel. NEC says the center of the grip of the handle of the highest breaker, can't be higher than 6'7".

Contact your local government to determine if there's a local amendment, that sets a minimum height.

Comment: Thanks. The local inspector said there's no amendments around here that affect the standard.